# How to make Docker Desktop UI bigger?

Tags: docker

Docker Desktop's UI is too small on my high DPI monitor. This makes it hard to read what is on the screen at times. How can I make the text and buttons larger?

Answer (score 2):

`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `+` will let you increase the text size

`Ctrl` + `-` will let you decrease the text size